# How to replace URL within hyperlinks in multiple Google Docs with a Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, hyperlink, google-docs

Background: I have about 1500 Google Docs in a Google Services account shared directory. Some of those docs have hyperlinks. I need to replace the URL in hyperlinks with new URLs using a Google Script.

I found this script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755956/google-scripts-find-and-replace-function-that-searches-multiple-documents). The script below will successfully replace URL's within the body of any Google Doc in my drive, but it will not replace any URL's within hyperlinks.

How can I modify this script to replace the URL within a hyperlink instead of just the body text?

```
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();   // Note: this gets *every* file in your Google Drive
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
    doc.replaceText("http://www.googledoclink1.com", "http://www.googledoclinkA.com");
    doc.replaceText("http://www.googledoclink2.com", "http://www.googledoclinkB.com");// Note: This will be repeated probably 500 times
  }
  Logger.log("Done")
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by replacing a URL within a hyperlink? Could do provide a sample Docs file showing what should be change to what?

Comment: I mean a URL within the body text was replaced successfully by the script. A URL within a hyperlink (e.g. "Click here!" with the URL embedded) was not replaced by the script above. Here's a sample doc: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ozOq8g1Yu8xQCn4EFY5L1_a7mhMLN1d7i87l-_YAcRI/edit

Answer (score 3):

### You need to replace both the text and the hyperlink separately

The hyperlink can be modified with `setLinkUrl()`.

Modify your code in a following way to make it work:

```
function myFunction() {
  var oldLink="http://www.googledoclink1.com";
  var newLink="http://www.googledoclinkA.com";
  var oldLink2="http://www.googledoclink2.com";
  var newLink2="http://www.googledoclinkB.com";
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();   // Note: this gets *every* file in your Google Drive
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
    var link=doc.getBody().findText(oldLink).getElement().asText(); 
    var link2=doc.getBody().findText(oldLink2).getElement().asText(); 
    link.setLinkUrl(newLink);   
    doc.replaceText(oldLink, newLink);
    link2.setLinkUrl(newLink2);   
    doc.replaceText(oldLink2, newLink2);
  }
  Logger.log("Done")
}
```

Comment: See my solution for a document wide search & replace (only hyperlinks):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636525/164374