# Replace Hyperlinks in Multiple Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, hyperlink, google-docs, drive

**I entered the following code posted by ziganotschka on https://stackoverflow.com/a/57865441/12252776:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var oldLink="http://www.googledoclink1.com";
  var newLink="http://www.googledoclinkA.com";
  var oldLink2="http://www.googledoclink2.com";
  var newLink2="http://www.googledoclinkB.com";
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();   // Note: this gets *every* file in your Google Drive
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
    var link=doc.getBody().findText(oldLink).getElement().asText(); 
    var link2=doc.getBody().findText(oldLink2).getElement().asText(); 
    link.setLinkUrl(newLink);   
    doc.replaceText(oldLink, newLink);
    link2.setLinkUrl(newLink2);   
    doc.replaceText(oldLink2, newLink2);
  }
  Logger.log("Done")
}
```

**...but I get this error message:**

```
TypeError: Cannot call method "getElement" of null. (line 11, file "Replace Hyperlinks")
```

How do I fix this? What do I have to do?

I also just wanted to pull files from a folder and not all files in my Google Drive, so I replaced

```
var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
```

with

```
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("insert folder ID").getFiles();
```

That would work, right?

Thank you, 
Lauren

Comment: In your script, if there are no texts of `http://www.googledoclink1.com` and `http://www.googledoclink2.com` in the Google Document, such error occurs. So please confirm this again. If the same error occurs even when you modified this, can you provide a sample Google Document for replicating the issue? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Hi, I should have clarified that I changed the links to my own links. Both the links and the code to pull files from a specific folder are the only things I modified in ziganotschka's code.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed an answer has already been posted and also the discussion has already been advanced. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your first question:

- You are iterating through all files on your drive /in your folder
- Some of those files might not contain the old link "http://www.googledoclink1.com"
- This throws you the error
- You need to implement a statement that checks either the link is contained, and if not - jump to the next file

To your second question:

- Yes, you can use `var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("insert folder ID").getFiles();`
- You can also use `var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("insert folder ID").getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);` to retrieve only Google Docs files

Sample:

```
function myFunction() {
  var oldLink="http://www.googledoclink1.com";
  var newLink="http://www.googledoclinkA.com";
  var oldLink2="http://www.googledoclink2.com";
  var newLink2="http://www.googledoclinkB.com";
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("insert folder ID").getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    if(file){
      var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
      var link=doc.getBody().findText(oldLink);
      var link2=doc.getBody().findText(oldLink2);
      if(link){
        link=link.getElement().asText(); 
        link.setLinkUrl(newLink);   
        doc.replaceText(oldLink, newLink);
      }
      if(link2){
        link2=link2.getElement().asText(); 
        link2.setLinkUrl(newLink2);   
        doc.replaceText(oldLink2, newLink2);
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log("Done")
}
```

**ADDITION:**

Addressing your comment

> Example: Suppose I had the hyperlink text: "Symptom to Diagnosis: An
>   Evidence-Based Guide, 3e" with the URL
>   accessmedicine.mhmedical.com/book.aspx?bookid=1088. I want to replace
>   that hyperlink text with "Symptom to Diagnosis: An Evidence-Based
>   Guide, 4e" with the URL
>   accessmedicine.mhmedical.com/book.aspx?bookid=2715. So, I want to find
>   every instance of the old hyperlink and replace it with the new
>   hyperlink. I'm wondering where all that belongs in the code...does it
>   need quotation marks?

Sample solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  var oldLinkText="Symptom to Diagnosis: An Evidence-Based Guide, 3e";
  var newLinkText="Symptom to Diagnosis: An Evidence-Based Guide, 4e";
  var oldLinkURL="accessmedicine.mhmedical.com/book.aspx?bookid=1088";
  var newLinkURL="accessmedicine.mhmedical.com/book.aspx?bookid=2715";
  var oldLinkText2="XXX";
  var newLinkText2="XXY";
  var oldLinkURL2="accessmedicine.XXX";
  var newLinkURL2="accessmedicine.XXY";
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("insert folder ID").getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);  
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    if(file){
      var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
      var link=doc.getBody().findText(oldLinkText);
      var link2=doc.getBody().findText(oldLinkText2);
      if(link){
        link=link.getElement().asText(); 
        link.setLinkUrl(newLinkURL);   
        doc.replaceText(oldLinkText, newLinkText);
      }
      if(link2){
        link2=link2.getElement().asText(); 
        link2.setLinkUrl(newLinkURL2);   
        doc.replaceText(oldLinkText2, newLinkText2);
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log("Done")
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have clarified that I changed the URL links above to links that might appear in my Google docs. Both the links and the "pull files from a specific folder" code are the only things I modified in your original code. Where it says "replace text", is this where I write the old and new link text? (not the URLs) Also, does this new code above contain the statement you mention that checks whether the link is contained, and if not - jumps to the next file? Thank you.

Comment: The statement `if(link)` verifies either the link text with the value `oldLink` is contained in the text - and if it does, replaces both the link text and the URL with `newLink`. If `oldLink` is not contained, the code jumps directly to `oldLink2`. If none of both is contained, it jumps to the next document (otherwise you will get an error by trying to replace a text which is non-existant). And yes, "replace text" is where the link text gets replaced.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Example: Suppose I had the hyperlink text: "Symptom to Diagnosis: An Evidence-Based Guide, 3e" with the URL https://accessmedicine.mhmedical.com/book.aspx?bookid=1088. I want to replace that hyperlink text with "Symptom to Diagnosis: An Evidence-Based Guide, 4e" with the URL https://accessmedicine.mhmedical.com/book.aspx?bookid=2715. So, I want to find every instance of the old hyperlink and replace it with the new hyperlink. I'm wondering where all that belongs in the code...does it need quotation marks?

Comment: I made an addition to my answer, hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: The only thing is that I'm having trouble making it work when I add other hyperlinks that need to be changed, in addition to the links already in the code: var oldLinkText2="Harrison's Principles of Internal Medicine, 19e";
  var newLinkText2="Harrison's Principles of Internal Medicine, 20e";
  var oldLinkURL2="accessmedicine.mhmedical.com/book.aspx?bookid=1130";
  var newLinkURL2="accessmedicine.mhmedical.com/book.aspx?bookid=2129";

Comment: Glad it worked. For the other links you can proceed analogously:  `var link2=doc.getBody().findText(oldLinkText2); if(link2){...}`  If my answer was helpful for you, I would appreciate if you consider accepting it.

Comment: Accepted! Thank you. I kept all the above code and just added this before the three consecutive brackets but it's not working:                                                                                          
      var link2=doc.getBody().findText(oldLinkText2); 
      if(link2){
        link2=link2.getElement().asText(); 
        link2.setLinkUrl(newLinkURL2);   
        doc.replaceText(oldLinkText2, newLinkText2);

Comment: It looks correct to me (provided you closed the curly bracket of the if statement). I will add it into the code part of my answer so you can doublecheck that you added the additional code into the correct position.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you soo much @ziganotschka !!! Learned a lot!!

Comment: No worries, happy to help.